# Is there Logical Folders in Pycharm or Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, pycharm

Sometimes we need to work with files in different folders.
Is there a feature in Pycharm or Eclipse that enable us to mark files with tags (or something similar) and show them in logical folders or groups?

Comment: What do you mean by "different folders"?  Explain how you're working, or what you're working on.

Comment: It's an accounting reporting project which handles many reports such as: Ledger, Profit and Loss, Balance Sheet, etc. They all share some common files but every one has its own specific files. I want to separate the files of each report logically.

Comment: I want to achieve something like tags in Gmail where an email message can belong to many folders but it's impossible in the traditional folder structure. So, the tags idea solved this by marking each message with any number of  tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it.

I can just use (Favorites):

1. Right Click any file and choose (Add to Favorites).
2. Select one of the existing lists or add a new one.
3. To see your favorite lists: Press Alt+2 or click View --> Tool
   Windows --> Favorites